# Meaning of Mehrfamilienhaus

Tags: meaning

Ich weiß nicht, was *Mehrfamilienhaus* bedeutet. Und was ist der Unterschied zwischen einem Apartment und einem Mehrfamilienhaus?

Comment: Is there anything you didn't understand in the descriptions in [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mehrfamilienhaus) or [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mehrfamilienhaus)?

Comment: Exactly yes! Die Erklärungen sind nicht klar für mich 

Comment: Bitte sag genauer, *was* du nicht verstehst. Ansonsten werden unsere Definitionen nicht viel anders ausfallen als die der Wörterbücher; gerade bei _Mehrfamilienhaus_, das eine recht durchsichtige Zusammensetzung ist.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Mehrfamilienhaus ist ein Haus, in dem mehrere Familien wohnen.

Ein [Mehrfamilienhaus](http://muenchen.neubaukompass.de/bilder/objekt/1231/1-gross.png) besteht in der Regel aus mehreren, voneinander getrennten Wohnungen.

Comment: DANKESCHÖN ✌ aber was ist der unterschied zwischen Apartment und Mehrfamilienhaus???!

Comment: @M.ans Ein *Apartment* bezeichnet niemals ein Haus, sondern immer eine Wohnung (die sich *in* einem Haus befindet).

Comment: @Matthias  danke vielmals, ich verstehe was habe ich nicht verstanden! Ich glaube ich muss zuerst die Bedeutung von Haus und Wuhnung verstehen 

Comment: @chirlu  ich bin jetzt im A2 Stufe,Ihre Sätze sind schwer für mich zum verstehen 

Comment: Ein Haus =  a house

Comment: @M.ans Was ist Deine Muttersprache? Das könnte helfen, Dir den Unterschied zu erklären.

Comment: @HolgT Ich bin zuvor auch diesem Automatismus gefolgt - aber eigentlich gibt es keinen Anlass anzunehmen, dass M.ans Englisch besser versteht als Deutsch.

Comment: @Mathias: Entschuldigung, ich hatte es gerade editiert, kam dann aber ins Timeout:

Daher

Haus: ein Haus für ein oder mehrere Familien (Wohnungen) Mehrfamilienhaus: ein Haus gebaut für mehrere Familien (Wohnungen/apartments) Wenn ein Haus für eine Familie erweitert wird (zum Beispiel Dachbodenausbau) um eine Wohnung, spricht man nicht von einem Mehrfamilienhaus

Comment: @Matthias danke schön für ihre Hilfe. Ich kann ein bisschen Deutsch und etwas Englisch . Meine Muttersprachler ist ganz anderes!

Comment: Ich bedanke dich @HolgT für deine Antwort 

Answer (score 1):

### Apartment

Ein Apartment ist eine Wohnung, die sich in einem Haus befindet. Ein Apartment ist selbst kein Haus. Der Eingang zum Apartment befindet sich nicht an der Außenseite des Hauses (seltene Ausnahmen gibt es aber). Man betritt also zuerst das Haus, bewegt sich im Haus zum Eingang des Apartments (häufig indem man das Treppenhaus benutzt oder mit einem Aufzug nach oben fährt) und betritt erst dann das Apartment.

### Mehrfamilienhaus

Das ist ein Haus, in dem sich mehrere Wohnungen befinden, die groß genug sind um jeweils einzelnen Familien Platz zu bieten. Die Wohneinheiten sind also keine Single-Wohnungen.

Mehrfamilienhäuser fassen meist zwei bis vier Wohnungen zusammen, die sich z.B. eine gemeinsame Heizanlage teilen. Häufig liegen diese Wohnungen ebenerdig, jeweils mit eigenem Garten, und häufig hat jede dieser Wohnung einen eigenen Hauseingang. All diese Eigenschaften sind aber nicht zwingend notwendig.

Bei Häusern, die Wohnungen für mehr als vier Familien bieten, könnte man zwar auch von Mehrfamilienhäusern sprechen, jedoch ist hier der Begriff »*Wohnhaus*« oder »*Wohnhausanlage*« gängiger.

Comment: Unter "Wohnhaus" verstehe ich das Gegenteil von "Geschäftshaus" und eine "Wohnhausanlage" (so man den Begriff benutzen will) ist meiner Erfahrung nach eine Gruppe von (Mehrfamilien-)Häusern, die meist von einem Bauträger gemeinsam erbaut wurden und oft einen gleichen oder ähnlichen Grundriss aufweisen (-> Kostenreduktion, Gewinnmaximierung). Kann natürlich nicht ausschließen, dass in Ö. andere Begriffe üblich sind als in D. Und ich hätte massive Probleme, in den üblichen Entwürfen für Mehrfamilienhäuser mit 4 Einheiten jeder einen Garten zuzuordnen - 2x2 Wohnungen ist m.E. Standard.

Comment: @Stephie: In dem Haus in dem ich wohne befinden sich 49 Wohnungen, aufgeteilt auf 7 Etagen: 14 Dreizimmer-Wohnungen und 35 Zweizimmer-Wohnungen. (Jeweils ein Wohnzimmer plus ein oder zwei Schlafzimmer.) Dazu eine Garage mit 49 Stellplätzen, Müllraum, Fahrradraum, zwei Kellergeschoße mit Einlagerungsräumen und einige Betriebsräume die für die Bewohner nicht zugänglich sind. Wie würdest du so ein Haus bezeichnen? Ein Mehr**familien**haus ist es jedenfalls nicht, weil in 35 der 49 Wohnungen mangels Kinderzimmer keine Familien, sondern nur Singles oder Paare wohnen können.

Comment: *Mehrfamilienhaus*. Auch wenn es keine formaljuristische Definition des Begriffs Mehrfamilienhaus gibt wird der Begriff für Gebäude mit mehreren Wohneinheiten benutzt, die *nicht zwingend von Familien* sondern von beliebig großen Eigentümer- oder Mietparteien (1 - n) bewohnt werden. Dazu gibt es sowohl Quellen aus dem Bau- als auch dem Wirtschafts- und Steuerrecht. Regional wird auch (weniger irreführend) "Mehrparteienhaus" benutzt.